# Memory address space of a process

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, malloc

I know that Windows 32-bit allows for any process about 2 Gigabyte memory address space as a maximum. 2 Gigabytes = 2147483648 bytes. I tried to allocate heap memory much more than 2147483648 bytes and I saw no error or exception, this the code:

```
# include<iostream>

int main(){

    void *x=malloc(2147489999);
    free(x);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

what is the reason?

Comment: how do you think an error or warning should be signalled?

Comment: exceptions or any other notifications?

Comment: C does not have exceptions, and `malloc` is C, not C++.  `malloc` indicates its failure by returning `NULL`.  You did not observe the return value.

Comment: `malloc` is included within C++ standard library.

Comment: I am wondering why some down-voted the Q!!

Comment: @Adban - `malloc` is C.  Lots of C code can be compiled as C++ but that doesn't mean that `malloc` suddenly requires C++ features that didn't exist when `malloc` was created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not checking the return value :)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

#define PAUSE getchar

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *x=malloc(2147489999);
    if (x)
    {
      printf ("malloc succeeded: 0x%x...\n", x);
      free(x);
    }
    else
    {
      perror ("malloc failed");
    }
    PAUSE ();
    return 0;
}
```

> C:\temp>\bin\vcvars32 Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual
>   C++ tools. C:\temp>notepad tmp.cpp
>
> C:\temp>cl tmp.cpp Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler
>   Version 12.00.8168 for 80x86 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> tmp.cpp ... /out:tmp.exe tmp.obj
>
> C:\temp>tmp malloc failed: No error

Comment: Oh! thanks paulsm4, but still I can not malloc 2 GB! try `malloc(2147483648 )`??

Comment: @Adban: Your *total* process address space is limited to 2 GB. Not just your data. The OS has to put your code somewhere, and all the DLLs you use, and any overhead reserved by the OS... if you want to allocate exactly 2 GB, you must use a 64-bit OS.